# I don't know how to set up apache2 subdomain redirect to other port

Tags: apache2, subdomain

I want to port redirect using apache2 on Ubuntu.

for example, I got a 3 subdomain in my site.
- my.kr
- blog.my.kr
- jira.my.kr

they are all listen 80. because for the beautiful url :D

now, I have a question!

blog.my.kr's real system on tomcat 8080
jira.my.kr's real system on tomcat 9090

in this case, how can I port forward in apache2?

just, using url address.

now I can just port forwarding, when blog.my.kr called, blog.my.kr:8080
but I don't want this way.
What I want is using blog.my.kr, not with :8080

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

not really sure to understand the question how it's formualted.
But did you look on mod_proxy ?
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

Or with tomcat a better solution can be http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html

cheers
fred